# How to pass boolean value from one component to another in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

In useState default value set to false and send it to login component. But login component is not getting the value(user, setUser).

```
import Login from "../Routes/Login";

const useAuth = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <Login user={user} setUser={setUser}></Login>
    </div>
  )
}
export default useAuth;
```

When  I am clicking on Login button it's causing an error called "Uncaught TypeError: setUser is not a function". When login button is clicked I want to change the value of "user" false to true.

```
const Login = ({ user, setUser }) => {
  
  console.log(user);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => { setUser(true) }}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Login;
```

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example of your issue: [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to replicate the issue that you mentioned. Here is the code sandbox link below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-pine-4edci7?file=/src/App.js

The naming convention that you used for the `useAuth` component is incorrect. From the naming convention it seems like it is a custom hook but rather it is a component.

So, you should use the following naming convention for it `UseAuth`. And it works fine in the above given codesandbox link.

Additional Note: All the custom hooks in reactjs are to be prefixed with `use` keyword. So, I would suggest to change the name of the component from `useAuth` to just `Auth` all together.